# react-facebook-login does not working after open website from facebook app

Tags: reactjs, facebook, facebook-login

I'm using React JS and react-facebook-login package,
I have a facebook page, in this facebook page I put the url of the related web page,login button works from any desktop browser and if I click on the link from desktop facebook, the problem is when I click on the link of the facebook page from my facebook app (android) it is as if the page were opened within the facebook app,

```
      <FacebookLoginWithButton
        appId="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        fields="link,first_name,middle_name,name,birthday,last_name,email,gender,locale,verified,picture.height(2048),age_range"
        callback={responseFacebook}
        textButton="Iniciar con facebook"
        isMobile={false}
      />
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the following changes and it works in facebook mobile browser:

```
   <FacebookLoginWithButton
                appId="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                fields="link,first_name,middle_name,name,birthday,last_name,email,gender,locale,verified,picture.height(2048),age_range"
                callback={responseFacebook}
                autoLoad={true}
                disableMobileRedirect={true}
                textButton="Iniciar con facebook"
                isMobile={false}
              />
```